# Gradually change height of a div based on width with css

Tags: html, css

I have a fluid container and I want its height to gradually change based on the width of the window (since the with of the div is 100%).
Note that the desired behavior is similar to the one when the aspect-ratio css rule is applied, which is a linear gradual increase/decrease.
Such variation should stop at a certain min and max height.

I understand that some js might be required, so I am open to it if css alone fails.

Comment: Can you please share some code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, "I would like to do something, please tell me how" is not a suitable question for Stackoverflow

Comment: You can define the height of your container using the `vw` [unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) to have the height change when the width does. Simply pick the ratio you're looking for (0.5vw, 0.75vw, etc...).

Comment: `vw / vh` are a good way to go with you don't wanna go the media queries way.

Comment: What do you want me to add? An empty div? It's just a simple question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into different available units of width in css. Mainly the `vh` and `vw`. In the example below you can see a div, with a height of 10% of viewport width, and width of 10% of viewport height.

```css
div {
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vw;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>Custom div</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you!